# Is a Java EE server required when project is made with Spring web?

Tags: java, spring, spring-web

I started developing a rest service with JavaEE + Glassfish and I noticed Glassfish is no longer in a good position in terms of development from Oracle. I ran into a few bugs that were not being fixed for months despite many reports from users. I decided not to use Glassfish.

I started researching about Spring, does a rest web service developed with Spring need a full EE compatible web server like Glassfish or Tomee? or would it run on something as basic as Apache Tomcat?

Comment: *"I noticed Glassfish is no longer in a good position in terms of development from Oracle."* ... for a supported open source Glassfish with ongoing quarterly releases, look to http://www.payara.fish

Comment: Just curious: anything in particular wrong with Wildfly/JBoss?

Comment: Use Apache Tomcat Server 8.0 which is a bug free , please don't install a Apache Tomcat 9.0 , in which they are fixing the issue. As I am using for Spring MVC and Restful Services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring does not require a full EE stack, it will run fine in Tomcat or [Jetty](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Spring). See also, [Spring Framework - Chapter 1. Basic Application and Environment Setup](https://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html) which demonstrates using Tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, spring and JEE are competing technologies. However, to build web-apps spring-web uses the servlet specification from JEE stack. This means that any JEE or servlet container can host these web-apps.

Modern spring developers often use spring-boot, which embeds a lightweight http server in a single executable uber-jar. I'd highly recommend that you try it out.